# SymPy: lambdify with 2-D inputs

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm computing a square matrix `V`, each element of which is an integral that I compute with `sympy`. I compute only *one* definite integral `V_nm`, the result of which is a numerical expression with symbolic indices `m` and `n`. Say `V_nm` looks like this:

```
>>> V_nm
sin(3*n)*cos(m)
```

Now I wish to make a 2-D *numerical* (not symbolic!) matrix out of `V_nm` using `m` and `n` as indices of the array. Say for a *2 x 2* matrix, the result for the given `V_nm` would be:

```
[[sin(3)cos(1) sin(3)cos(2)]
 [sin(6)cos(1) sin(6)cos(2)]]
```

i.e., `n` specifies the column and `m` specifies the rows. (Note: I start `m` and `n` at *1* and not *0*, but that's no concern).

How do I achieve this?
I know I can use `V_nm.subs([(n, ...), (m, ...)])` in a list comprehension followed by `evalf()` but that's the long route. I wish to achieve this using `lambdify`. I know how to use `lambdify` for 1-D arrays. Can you please tell me how to implement it for 2-D arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking doesn't look like a standard functionality. But in two steps it's possible. First [lambdify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) the expression, and then create a function that generates the intended 2D array via numpy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```py
from sympy import sin, cos, lambdify
from sympy.abc import m, n
import numpy as np

V_mn = sin(3 * n) * cos(m)

V_mn_np = lambdify((m, n), V_mn)
# using list comprehension:
# V_mn_np2D = lambda m, n: np.array([[V_mn_np(i, j) for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)])
# using numpy's broadcasting (faster for large arrays):
V_mn_np2D = lambda m, n: V_mn_np(np.arange(m)[:, None], np.arange(n))

V_mn_np2D(2, 2)
```

To have the numbering start at 1 instead of 0, use `np.arange(1, m+1)` and `np.arange(1, n+1)`.

As a test, a function such as `100 * m + n` makes it easy to verify that the approach works as intended.

```py
W_mn = 100 * m + n

W_mn_np = lambdify((m, n), W_mn)
W_mn_np2D = lambda m, n: W_mn_np(np.arange(1, m+1)[:, None], np.arange(1, n+1))

W_mn_np2D(2, 3)
```

Output:

```
array([[101, 102, 103],
       [201, 202, 203]])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is sympy's `FunctionMatrix` which is intended for this kind of case. Note that it uses zero-based indexing:

```
In [1]: m, n, i, j = symbols('m, n, i, j')                                                                                        

In [2]: V_nm = FunctionMatrix(m, n, Lambda((i, j), 100*(i+1) + (j+1)))                                                            

In [3]: V_nm                                                                                                                      
Out[3]: [100⋅i + j + 101]

In [4]: V_nm.subs({m:2, n:3}).as_explicit()                                                                                       
Out[4]: 
⎡101  102  103⎤
⎢             ⎥
⎣201  202  203⎦

In [5]: lambdify((m, n), V_nm)(2, 3)                                                                                              
Out[5]: 
array([[101., 102., 103.],
       [201., 202., 203.]])
```

Comment: With sympy 1.5.1 I got an error about `FunctionMatrix` not being found when trying to call `lambdify`. But after upgrading to sympy 1.6 it works nicely.